# Extract store and location using regex and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, extract

I want to extract store name and location from the `to_clean` column. I would like to use some regex pattern that accounts for all the different patterns and stores the store name in the `store` column and the location name in the `location` column.

Something like this:

```
to_clean = ['ACTIVE BODY #1 - WEST VAN', 'BUY-LOW (80018) - KINGSGATE', 'CHOICES - CAMBIE #906',
     'CAUSEWAY MASSET - CAMBIE', 'COMMUNITY NATURAL S2 - CHINOOK', 'MEINHARDT - GRANVILLE (80068)',
     'WFM - CAMBIE - 10248']

store = ['ACTIVE BODY', 'BUY-LOW', 'CHOICES', 'CAUSEWAY MASSET', 'COMMUNITY NATURAL', 'MEINHARDT', 'WFM']

location = ['WEST VAN', 'KINGSGATE', 'CAMBIE','CAMBIE', 'CHINOOK', 'GRANVILLE', 'CAMBIE']

data = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(to_clean, store, location)), columns=['to_clean', 'store', 'location'])
data
```

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @Naveed I understand it like `to_clean` is what he has, and the other 2 column is what he wants (but doesn't have)

Comment: dah! you're right @Rabinzel, :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (I stored the new values under `_new` columns):

```py
data["store_new"] = (
    data["to_clean"]
    .str.extract(r"^((?:[A-Z]|(?<=[A-Z])-|\s)+)\b")[0]
    .str.strip()
)
data["location_new"] = (
    data["to_clean"]
    .str.extract(r"((?:[A-Z]|(?<=[A-Z])-|\s)+)[^A-Z]*$")[0]
    .str.strip()
)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
                         to_clean              store   location          store_new location_new
0       ACTIVE BODY #1 - WEST VAN        ACTIVE BODY   WEST VAN        ACTIVE BODY     WEST VAN
1     BUY-LOW (80018) - KINGSGATE            BUY-LOW  KINGSGATE            BUY-LOW    KINGSGATE
2           CHOICES - CAMBIE #906            CHOICES     CAMBIE            CHOICES       CAMBIE
3        CAUSEWAY MASSET - CAMBIE    CAUSEWAY MASSET     CAMBIE    CAUSEWAY MASSET       CAMBIE
4  COMMUNITY NATURAL S2 - CHINOOK  COMMUNITY NATURAL    CHINOOK  COMMUNITY NATURAL      CHINOOK
5   MEINHARDT - GRANVILLE (80068)          MEINHARDT  GRANVILLE          MEINHARDT    GRANVILLE
6            WFM - CAMBIE - 10248                WFM     CAMBIE                WFM       CAMBIE
```

Answer (score 1):

here is one way to do it

Assumptions:

1. The store and location are separate by hyphen surrounded by spaces on both sides

```
# split  on ' - '
df[['store-1', 'location-1']] = df['to_clean'].str.split(r' - ',1, expand=True) 

# remove (),numbers
df[['store-1', 'location-1']]=df[['store-1', 'location-1']].replace(r'#\d+|\(\d+\)|\-\s\d+', '', regex=True) 
df
```

```
    to_clean                                    store   location        store-1           location-1
0   ACTIVE BODY #1 - WEST VAN               ACTIVE BODY     WEST VAN    ACTIVE BODY       WEST VAN
1   BUY-LOW (80018) - KINGSGATE                 BUY-LOW     KINGSGATE   BUY-LOW           KINGSGATE
2   CHOICES - CAMBIE #906                       CHOICES     CAMBIE      CHOICES           CAMBIE
3   CAUSEWAY MASSET - CAMBIE            CAUSEWAY MASSET     CAMBIE      CAUSEWAY MASSET   CAMBIE
4   COMMUNITY NATURAL S2 - CHINOOK    COMMUNITY NATURAL     CHINOOK     COMMUNITY NATURAL S2 CHINOOK
5   MEINHARDT - GRANVILLE (80068)             MEINHARDT     GRANVILLE   MEINHARDT         GRANVILLE
6   WFM - CAMBIE - 10248                            WFM     CAMBIE      WFM               CAMBIE
```